# cakephp undefined index when definitely defined

Tags: cakephp-2.0, cakephp-model

For reference, please visit [this page here](http://rentcondos4less.cloudmedia.biz/restaurants/seafood).  When trying to get a view display on one particular model, I am getting an undefined index error.  Specifically, any data from my Coupon model.  Here is my controller code:

```
public function seafood() {

$this->paginate['Restaurant']=array(
        'limit'=>9,
        'order' => 'RAND()',
        'contain'=>array(
                'User'=>array(
                    'id', 'user_name'),

                'Coupon'=>array(
                    'id','description','expires','end_date','promo_code','restaurant_id')
                    ),
        'conditions'=>array(

                'Restaurant.active'=>1,
                'Restaurant.seafood'=>'Seafood'
                )   
    );
$data = $this->paginate('Restaurant');
$this->set('seafood', $data);
```

when I debug($seafood) in my view, all data for Coupon shows, so I know it is correctly pulling data and associating it with my Restaurant model.  However, when I create a foreach loop with my $seafood array, I get nothing but undefined index errors for anything Coupon-related.  What's weird is that I also have my controller pulling from the User model and anything I call up from that model in the view gets rendered.  Here is my view code:

```
 <?php foreach ($seafood as $res) { ?>
        .....irrelevant code.....
 <p><?php if($res['Coupon']['description'] !=''){
        echo $this->Text->truncate($res['Coupon']['description'], 200, array('ending'=>'...', 'exact'=>false) );
        }
        else echo 'Sorry, a description of this restaurant\'s promotion is not available.  <br><br><br>';
         ?><a href="<?php echo $res['Restaurant']['website']; ?>"><em> (read more -->)</em></a></p>
    <br />
    <div>
    <a href="<?php echo $res['Restaurant']['website']; ?>" id="specials"><span style="margin-left:36px;">Promo Code:&nbsp;&nbsp;<span style="font-style:bold; color:#FF0000;"><?php echo $res['User']['user_name']; ?></span></span></a>
    <a href=" " id="print"><span style="margin-left:24px;">Print</span></a>
<?php } ?>
   ......more irrelevant code.....
```

I have tried removing the containable behavior from the array but the results are the same.  I should point out that when the debug array prints, it goes in order:  Restaurant, User, Coupon.  Is cake somehow losing the Coupon array because it is 3rd?  Or is my view code just screwy?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Looks like Restaurant hasMany Coupon so Coupon is an indexed array. You'll need a nested for loop.

```
foreach ($seafood as $res) {
    //irrelevant
    foreach ($res['Coupon'] as $coupon) {
        if($coupon['description'] !=''){
            //do stuff
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: That was it, thank you!  Now I actually understand a little more about cakephp and programming in general.  Thanks very much!